# How many 301 redirects will the google bot handle?

Tags: google

If your page does five 301 redirects to get to the final page I'm guessing that google bot will follow it all the way there. However, there must be a limit at which point google bot says "hey, that's enough, I'm not going any further." What is that limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They recommend no more than 5, although they don't specifically say they won't follow more than that. Plus, if it's a lot, it will hit your page load time, which will have a seriously negative impact on your SEO.

> Quentin, Vancouver: How many chained 301 redirects does Google not "like"?
>
> Nathan J: It's ok to chain a few together; I would avoid doing a whole bunch, like 20 or 30. :)
>
> JohnMu: As far as I know, the HTTP 1.0 standard allows for a maximum of 5 redirects for a URL. That said, search engines might treat it in different ways, so I'd recommend reducing the redirects to a minimal number.

[Google Webmaster Group](http://groups.google.com/group/Google_Webmaster_Help/web/q-a-from-the-3rd-live-chat-oct-2008?pli=1)

Comment: Matt Cutts, in [the following YouTube video (2011)](https://youtu.be/r1lVPrYoBkA?t=165) describes "4 or 5 redirects" as being "dangerous".