# Four 301-redirects from "www.example.com" to "shop.example.com" (am I losing my Google PageRank?)

Tags: seo, apache, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, pagerank

Some years ago, I started my website with the main domain `www.example.com`. However, the project ended up being a store under `shop.example.com`.

I obtained hundreds of links to `http://www.example.com`, and today (after two years) I found that the redirection is not well-constructed, because there are four 301-redirects from `http://www.example.com` to `https://shop.example.com`.

I have two questions:

1. Should I fix urgently this issue of "too many 301-redirects" in order not to lose my Google PageRank?
2. Is there any quick Rewrite Rule for Apache 301-redirect from `http://www.example.com` to `https://shop.example.com`?

Comment: "four 301-redirects" - Do you mind sharing the redirect chain you are seeing? It's difficult to imagine how you get 4 redirects (5 unique URLs) between those 2 URLs?!

Comment: I can imagine 8 possible URLs that could be involved:  `http://www.example.com/`,  `https://www.example.com/`, `http://example.com/`,  `https://example.com/`, `http://shop.example.com/`,  `https://shop.example.com/`, `http://www.shop.example.com/`,  `https://www.shop.example.com/`.

Comment: See also: [How many 301 redirects will the google bot handle?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12241/how-many-301-redirects-will-the-google-bot-handle)

Answer (score 2):

Well, its been 2 years so urgent is relative, but yes, you want to fix this as each redirect is believed to come with a small loss of "google juice".

Matt Cutts (a google official rep) talked about it being unlikely that Google will follow 4 or more redirects - although that was a while ago (see https://youtu.be/r1lVPrYoBkA?t=165 from about 2:45)

There are multiple ways to set up a redirect in Apache. The easiest one in your code might be - in the Apache config or `.htaccess` -

```
  Redirect permanent / https://shop.example.com/
```

(Ref: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent)

Comment: "its been 2 years" - I would also be curious to know how many of these sites are still linking to the "old" URL? I would like to think that any site of worth would have performed a link audit at some point during this time, particularly with the big push to HTTPS everywhere. (?)